# Rmarkdown space without line break ~

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

In Latex, it is possible to insert a space that does not end a line by a `~` character. So writing `Fig.~\ref{fig:f1}` will write as

> Fig. 1

and it makes sure that text wrapping never breaks a line between Fig. and the number 1.

However, in Rmarkdown writing `Fig.~\@ref(fig:f1)`, `Fig.\~\@ref(fig:f1)`, or `Fig.\\~\@ref(fig:f1` translates to `Fig.\textasciitilde{}\ref{fig:f1}` giving

> Fig.~1

in the output.
How do you insert the equivalent of `~` in rmarkdown? I am actually using bookdown.

Answer (score 15):

Insert a [`n`on `b`reaking `sp`ace](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) manually using regular HTML:

```
...Fig.&nbsp;\@ref{fig:f1}...
```

Comment: Great! It even translates correctly to Latex and PDF (i.e., non HTML formats).

Comment: Thanks so much! This even works if used in a r inline code chunk, e.g. within `\`r paste0(x, "&nbsp;", y)\``. Very handy! (I tried this in the `docx` output)

Answer (score 6):

Use `\`  i.e. backslash then a space.

```
Fig.\ \@ref{fig:f1}
```

You could also use `$~$`, but this works only for PDF.

```
Fig.$~$\@ref{fig:f1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`~` is just a shortcut for `\nobreakspace{}`. You can directly use the underlying macro to avoid rmarkdown interfering with the tilde:

```
test\nobreakspace{}test
```