# Using R, RStudio Knit to PDF, how to pass tilde to prevent line wrapping "Table~\ref{table:data-from-phone}"?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, knitr-spin

In Latex, it is common to reference a label using the "~" to keep the number attached to the label such as Figure or Table.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227285/problems-with-tilde-and-line-breaking/227296 shows an example of this.

A fully working example can be found here:

http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/tilde/

In the Rmd file, http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/tilde/reference-tilde.Rmd,

I have the following:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
---


\section{My Section Name}
\label{sec:my}

Below you will find Equation~\ref{eq:my-model}.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:my-model}
    Y_{jt} = \alpha + \beta X_{jt} + \upsilon_{j}  + \varepsilon_{jt} ,
\end{equation}


\subsection{My sub section}
\label{sec:mysub}

For more information, please refer to Section~\ref{sec:my}.
```

Notice the "~" tilde being used as outlined in basic Latex usage.

When I click Knit-PDF, it outputs something I did not expect:

http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/tilde/reference-tilde.pdf

Since I choose "keep_tex", I can view the .TEX file

http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/tilde/reference-tilde.tex which can be seen online here: http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/tilde/reference-tilde.tex.txt

It appears to have replaced the tilde with a text version:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{My Section Name}
\label{sec:my}

Below you will find Equation\textasciitilde{}\ref{eq:my-model}.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:my-model}
    Y_{jt} = \alpha + \beta X_{jt} + \upsilon_{j}  + \varepsilon_{jt} ,
\end{equation}

\subsection{My sub section}
\label{sec:mysub}

For more information, please refer to
Section\textasciitilde{}\ref{sec:my}.

\end{document}
```

How do I rectify this situation?

How do I get the Latex to render as expected?

How do I get my tilde as a spacer back?

Comment: I feel it is a good point to rise an issue on `knitr` github (look at `escape_latex` function in https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/utils.R). Maybe the `gsub` pattern for `~` should avoid something like `\S~\ ` (written as if \ was not a special character. Now I do not find how to look for a `\ ` in regex...)

Comment: Now I found it. It should avoid at least `\\S~\\ref`, but also (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36924/8639) `\\S~\\d`.

Comment: You may want to consider `\usepackage{cleveref}` and use `\Cref{sec:my}` rather than `Section~\ref{sec:my}`.

Answer (score 4):

A unicode non-breaking space should work. Or pandoc parses even an HTML entity inside markdown into the correct thing, see e.g.

```
echo '&nbsp;foo' | pandoc -t latex

~foo
```

If you must include some hard to parse LaTeX in your markdown, you can use [generic raw attributes](https://www.pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute) like:

````
```{=latex}
my LaTeX
```
````

Comment: I am asking how to get "standard Latex syntax" to work in RMarkdown.  Under the hood, the "~" got replaced with "\textasciitilde{}" before being processed by pdflatex.  How do I prevent that replacement?  Your answer is "create new grammar and syntax" that is alien to the core of Latex.  When I want "\textasciitilde{}" or "\sim" I would use it.  For example, `\def\IIDdist{\,{\buildrel iid \over \sim}\,}`

Comment: Since you're writing markdown, I assumed you want markdown syntax? It seems you're under the mistaken impression that your input format is LaTeX. But in fact it's Rmd, which is basically [pandoc flavoured markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown), which can include raw latex... but is not intended to be used the way you use it. And that's the reason the `~` behaves like it does, it's not parsed as latex but as markdown.

Comment: So how do I block off a chunk of "flavoured markdown" to be pure Latex?

Comment: @mshaffer using ```{=latex}
, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute

Comment: I notice when I use `input{path/to/latex.file}` it does not parse the latex.  Let me try this other syntax.  What if I use a generic syntax ```{=text}```?

Comment: This works, if you want to update your answer ... expand it, or create a new answer.  I will check it as "answered"

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671612/how-to-type-tilde-in-formulas-in-rmarkdown), you can try replacing your tilde with "\~" or "\sim" and see which one works.
2. Since you kept the .tex file, you can always search+replace the `\textasciitilde{}` with a real tilde, even if #1 does not work.

Comment: I want it to behave like a "space" not a tilde.  That is, to behave like it should in Latex.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665579/rmarkdown-space-without-line-break ?

Comment: Thanks Michal.  You are just reinforcing the point.  RStudio is changing the established Latex syntax.  I don't want to create "new syntax", I want the "traditional syntax" to work.  Under the hood, they replaced "~" with "\textasciitilde{}".  How do I prevent that replacement?